# Why does yarn install command completes with errors on my project?

Tags: cucumber, yarnpkg, webdriver-io

yarn version 3.2.4
node version v18.12.0

After running `yarn install` I get the following error:

```
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0013: │ yargs@npm:17.6.2 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yarn-install@npm:1.0.0 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yauzl@npm:2.10.0 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yup@npm:0.32.11 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ zip-stream@npm:4.1.0 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 488ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0000: │ ESM support for PnP uses the experimental loader API and is therefore experimental
➤ YN0007: │ chromedriver@npm:107.0.3 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ es5-ext@npm:0.10.62 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 0s 738ms
```

Answer (score 0):

these error codes are totally fine and none of them are actually errors. They are more like logs with INFO levels. if it is an error, you might have seen the message with the prefix with the error. You can read more about these error codes [here](https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/error-codes#yn0000---unnamed).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to OP's warning message, I was also getting several error messages like the following:

```
YN0013: │ extsprintf@npm:1.4.1 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0001: │ Error [ERR_STREAM_PREMATURE_CLOSE]: Premature close
    at PassThrough.onclose (node:internal/streams/end-of-stream:154:30)
    at PassThrough.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at emitCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:147:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)
```

Thanks to @Raju's resourceful link, it seemed like `YN0001` "typically should never happen", so I figured I might want to upgrade my yarn version, which was `3.0.1`.

You can update your yarn version by running `yarn set version stable`.

Then when I ran `yarn`, although it was showing other warning messages, it at least completed!

```
yarn                                                                                                               ─╯
➤ YN0048: Automatically removed core plugins that are now builtins 

➤ YN0000: · Yarn 4.1.1
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0085: │ + @babel/core@npm:7.24.0, @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@npm:7.23.6, and 1846 more.
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 7s 971ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Post-resolution validation
➤ YN0060: │ @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin is listed by your project with version 5.62.0, which doesn't satisfy what eslint-config-react-app (pc2925) requests (^4.0.0).
➤ YN0060: │ @typescript-eslint/parser is listed by your project with version 5.62.0, which doesn't satisfy what eslint-config-react-app (p485af) requests (^4.0.0).
➤ YN0060: │ eslint-plugin-flowtype is listed by your project with version 4.7.0, which doesn't satisfy what eslint-config-react-app (p709f8) requests (^5.2.0).
➤ YN0060: │ react is listed by your project with version 18.2.0, which doesn't satisfy what @storybook/react (p1eae0) and other dependencies request (^16.8.0 || ^17.0.1).
➤ YN0060: │ react-dom is listed by your project with version 18.2.0, which doesn't satisfy what @storybook/react (p8018f) and other dependencies request (^16.8.0 || ^17.0.1).
➤ YN0002: │ primitives@workspace:. doesn't provide @testing-library/dom (p1178b), requested by @testing-library/user-event.
➤ YN0002: │ primitives@workspace:. doesn't provide require-from-string (p2e43f), requested by @storybook/react.
➤ YN0002: │ primitives@workspace:. doesn't provide webpack (pab42c), requested by babel-loader.
➤ YN0086: │ Some peer dependencies are incorrectly met; run yarn explain peer-requirements <hash> for details, where <hash> is the six-letter p-prefixed code.
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0013: │ 1812 packages were added to the project (+ 625.92 MiB).
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 8s 614ms
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0007: │ cypress@npm:8.7.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ husky@npm:4.3.8 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ core-js@npm:3.36.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ core-js-pure@npm:3.36.0 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ msgpackr-extract@npm:3.0.2 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ lmdb@npm:2.2.4 must be built because it never has been before or the last one failed
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 40s 672ms
➤ YN0000: · Done with warnings in 57s 426ms
```